# Normalised compass bearing from start to end point as lat, lng pairs

Tags: math, vb6

From the net:

> Since atan2 returns values in the range -π ... +π (that is, -180° ... +180°), to normalise the result to a compass bearing (in the range 0° ... 360°, with -ve values transformed into the range 180° ... 360°), convert to degrees and then use (θ+360) % 360, where % is modulo.

I'm using VB6 and my code is like this

```
brng = (θ + 360) Mod 360
```

where θ = -68

I'm getting the answer 292°,but expected answer is 248°.

am i committing a mistake..? or am I missing something.? Please help me.

**Update:**

I'll further explain my question,

```
Dim b As Double
Dim x As Double 
Dim y As Double 
Dim Dlat As Double 
Dim DLon As Double

Private Const pi As Double = 3.14159265358979

Public Function Atn2(ByVal y As Double, ByVal x As Double) As Double
    On Error GoTo DivideError
    Atn2 = Atn(y / x)
    If (x < 0) Then
        If (y < 0) Then Atn2 = Atn2 - vbPI Else Atn2 = Atn2 + vbPI
    End If
    Exit Function

DivideError:
    If Abs(y) > Abs(x) Then   'Must be an overflow
        If y > 0 Then Atn2 = vbPI / 2 Else Atn2 = -vbPI / 2
    Else
        Atn2 = 0   'Must be an underflow
    End If
    Resume Next
End Function


Public Sub AFAMP()
    lat1 = Val(Text1.Text) * pi / 180 'conveting to radians
    lat2 = Val(Text2.Text) * pi / 180
    Long1 = Val(Text3.Text) * pi / 180
    Long2 = Val(Text4.Text) * pi / 180
    Dlat = (lat1 - lat2)
    DLon = (Long1 - Long2)
    y = Math.Sin(DLon) * Math.Cos(lat2)
    x = Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Sin(lat2) - Math.Sin(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Cos(DLon)
    b = Atn2(y, x) * (180 / pi)
    Text5.Text = (b +360) mod 360
End Sub
```

*coordinates are as below in decimal degrees*

```
lat1 = Val(7.337361) * pi / 180 

lat2 = Val(7.000667) * pi / 180

Long1 = Val(81.626198) * pi / 180

Long2 = Val(80.773737) * pi / 180
```

I have checked with an [online coordinate calculator](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), the answer is 248. In my case it is 292 degrees. Can anyone please help me? I'm stuck.

Comment: Why are you expecting 248? `-68 + 360 = 292` You seem to be going the wrong way around.

Comment: I assume you're trying to calculate the bearing between two points.  I can't say exactly what the problem is, but I found something hopeful -- if I swap your point1 and point2 in that online calculator, I get a bearing of about 68deg.  Note that 68+292=360.  Perhaps your problem is just in your definition of bearing?

Comment: Please don't repeat the same question, update the original. I have done this for you.

Answer (score 0):

As Deanna said in a comment, 292 is the correct answer. `-68 + 360 = 292`

Comment: I have checked with the Google earth too,correct answer is 248,but i couldn't understand the way to real answer.
@Kev-i'm just elaborating on my question.
Thanks for editing my question in a nice manner.

Answer (score 0):

This code is JavaScript because I can't remember VB syntax.

Convert to degrees. Don't repeat this code, make it a method on Number. Or a first class function with two parameters, whatever your target language supports.

```js
  Number.prototype.toDegrees = function (unit) {
    const u = (unit || "d").toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    switch (u) {
      case 'r': //radians
        return this * 180 / Math.PI;
      case 'g': //grads
        return this * 200 / Math.PI;
      case 'd': //degrees
        return this;
      default: //radians
        return this * 180 / Math.PI;
    }
  };
```

Normalise the range.

```js
Number.prototype.toNormalisedDegrees = function () {
  return (this - 360 * (Math.trunc(this / 360) - 1)) % 360;
}
```

Rotate 90 degrees and reverse the direction.

```js
  Number.prototype.toCompassBearing = function (unit) {
    const degrees = unit && unit.toLowerCase().charAt(0) === "r" ? this.toDegrees() : this;
    return (90 - degrees).toNormalisedDegrees();
  }
```

### Test with some known values

```js
Number.prototype.toDegrees = function (unit) {
  const u = (unit || "d").toLowerCase().charAt(0);
  switch (u) {
case 'r':
  return this * 180 / Math.PI;
case 'g':
  return this * 200 / Math.PI;
default:
  return this;
  }
};
Number.prototype.toNormalisedDegrees = function () {
  return (this - 360 * (Math.trunc(this / 360) - 1)) % 360;
}
Number.prototype.toCompassBearing = function (unit) {
  return (90 - this.toDegrees(unit)).toNormalisedDegrees();
}

console.log(`0 cartesian (E) => ${(0).toCompassBearing("d")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`90 cartesian (N) => ${(90).toCompassBearing("d")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`90-22.5 cartesian (NNE) => ${(90-22.5).toCompassBearing("d")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`180 cartesian (W) => ${(180).toCompassBearing("d")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`-68 cartesian => ${(-68).toCompassBearing("d")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`-68 compass bearing => ${(-68).toNormalisedDegrees()} normalised degrees`);
console.log(`270 cartesian (S) => ${(270).toCompassBearing("d")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`0 cartesian (E) => ${(0).toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`PI/2 cartesian (N) => ${(0.5 * Math.PI).toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`PI cartesian (W) => ${Math.PI.toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`1.5 PI cartesian (S) => ${(1.5 * Math.PI).toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`2 PI cartesian (E) => ${(2 * Math.PI).toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`20 PI cartesian (E) => ${(20 * Math.PI).toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`-2 PI cartesian (E) => ${(-2 * Math.PI).toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`-2.5 PI cartesian (S) => ${(-2.5 * Math.PI).toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`-3 PI cartesian (W) => ${(-3 * Math.PI).toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
console.log(`-3.5 PI cartesian (N) => ${(-3.5 * Math.PI).toCompassBearing("r")} compass bearing`);
```

### If 292 is right, what's this 248 business?

You asked about converting a compass heading into normalised degrees, but the sample code you provide and the result you think is correct both suggest that what you actually want to do is determine the heading defined by start and end points expressed as Lat,Lng pairs, and express this in normalised degrees.

There's an article [here](https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/) suggesting a method and your code looks like a botched attempt to implement this.

This is what it looks like if you get it right in JavaScript.

```js
Number.prototype.toDegrees = function(unit) {
  const u = (unit || "d").toLowerCase().charAt(0);
  switch (u) {
    case 'r':
      return this * 180 / Math.PI;
    case 'g':
      return this * 200 / Math.PI;
    default:
      return this;
  }
};
Number.prototype.toRadians = function() {
  return this * Math.PI / 180;
}
Number.prototype.toNormalisedDegrees = function() {
  return (this - 360 * (Math.trunc(this / 360) - 1)) % 360;
}

function bearing(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
  const X = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(lng2 - lng1);
  const Y = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lng2 - lng1);
  return Math.atan2(X, Y);
}

const lat1 = (7.337361).toRadians();
const lng1 = (81.626198).toRadians();
const lat2 = (7.000667).toRadians();
const lng2 = (80.773737).toRadians();
const bearingRadians = bearing(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2);
const bearingDegrees = bearingRadians.toDegrees("radians");

console.log(`bearingRadians = ${bearingRadians}`);
console.log(`bearingDegrees = ${bearingDegrees}`);
console.log(`normalisedDegrees = ${bearingDegrees.toNormalisedDegrees()}`);
```

There are a couple of things to note.

- Latitude and Longitude are in the compass frame of reference and do not require conversion from the cartesian frame of reference.
- This code is written so that the result is in the compass frame of reference.
- The result is in radians and then converted to degrees.
- The degrees are then normalised to the 0-360 range.
- Using your inputs I get your expected output.